# PHP Colour Every Box in the Middle

Tags: php, html

I have a list of boxes on my website:

```
box1    box2    box3
box4    box5    box6
box7    box8    box9
```

Does anybody have a suggestion how to mark every box in the middle of the list (box2, box5, box8)?

Thanks for your help!

Here's my foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach($usersResult as $user) { ?>
    <div class="box">
        // other stuff here
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: How you are rendering them? Is there any loop used or the boxes are static?

Comment: @Shakti Singh Thanks for adding code first. I render them in a foreach loop, results comes from database. Just have no idea what approach I should use here.

Comment: Is the list of boxes an HTML table? Could you include the code that you use to make these boxes?

Comment: @rcollyer For me, it was related do maths.

Comment: @Mat Simple foreach PHP loop, nothing big.

Comment: @user342111223: please clarify the specif code you use.

Comment: @Trufa Sure. I'm editing the quesiton right now.

Comment: @user342111223 Add the code and you will get the help you need.

Comment: @Treffynnon Added the code - Like I said, nothing big :)

Comment: I'm sure it is simple. But until you post it, we can't tell you how to change it because we don't know what it *actually* does.

Comment: @Mat Yes, of course I know. Posted the code, trying the solutions posted in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($boxes as $box){
    if((($i+2) % 3) === 1){
        //box2, box5, box8
    }
    else{
       //other boxes
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: One small issue, $i should be 1 not 0. Working! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php $i=-1; foreach($usersResult as $user) { ?>
    <div class="box<?php echo ($i % 3 == 0 ? ' middle' : '') ?>">
        // other stuff here
    </div>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

**Explanation**: `%` (modulus operator) will return the remainder of a division. So if you do `$i % 3`, it will be `0` whenever `$i` is dividable by `3` (without remainder). I added `$i` into your loop, and I start it from `-1`, because we don't need every third element, but every third element starting from the second (in a 0 based world, the first).

I also used the ternary operator (`condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`).

Comment: Nice approach. Of course working. I've marked Yeroon's answer however. Let him collect some reputation ;) Thanks for support!

Comment: @user342111223 No problem, his code is working fine as well. I just wanted to show a bit different and maybe more compact approach.

Comment: Just fyi, your code has join in my snippet library ;) Amazing website ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should go with % and a for loop, something like this (not tested):

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    if( (($i+1)%3) == 0 ) echo 'class="colored"';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even slicker but lengthy - non Gofl example if you use arrays.

```
$boxes = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

foreach($boxes as $key => $box){
    echo (($key+2)%3==0) ? "<b>" : "";
    echo "(".$key . ' -> ' . $box . ") ";
    echo (($key+1)%3==0) ? "<br/>" : "";
    echo (($key+2)%3==0) ? "</b>" : "";
}
```

Output:

(0 -> 1) **(1 -> 2)** (2 -> 3)

(3 -> 4) **(4 -> 5)** (5 -> 6)

(6 -> 7) **(7 -> 8)** (8 -> 9)